# Session issue with codeigniter (CI)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am getting php session error on my live developed using codeigniter

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/userts4m/public_html/development/relatioweb/admin/index.php:1)

Filename: Session/Session.php

Line Number: 140

Backtrace:

File: /home/userts4m/public_html/development/relatioweb/application/admin/controllers/User.php
Line: 9
Function: __construct

File: /home/userts4m/public_html/development/relatioweb/admin/index.php
Line: 293
Function: require_once
```

Working at localhost fine. But when i uploded at server we are facing this issue.

What should i do ...

Comment: i think somewhere you forgot to remove print_r();die; or echo statement

Comment: what's on line 1 of this file? `/home/userts4m/public_html/development/relatioweb/admin/index.php`

Comment: Change something in constructor of `User.php` admin controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per `@kunal` and `@dale` suggestion there was a space in `/home/userts4m/public_html/development/relatioweb/admin/index.php`

Comment: i can't understand this answer?

Comment: @Jack ,I got above error when forget to remove single space in file at start

Answer (score 14):

There are two solutions to fix this issue.

Some times this error occurred due to the wrong configuration of the framework,
go to the folder `applications/config` and open up the `config.php` write this in the starting of file like this

```
<?php

  if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    ob_start();
    /* Remaining Part Of your file
     .........................................
   */
```

Another solution is to write `ob_start()` in the constructor of the class
like this:

```
<?php

 if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
   class Your_Controller extends CI_Controller {
     public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
       ob_start();
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 5):

the problem is well explained here [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

In order to solve this I needed to implement 
the concept of output-buffering (Output buffering is a mechanism in which instead of sending a response immediately to browser we buffer it somewhere so that we can send it at once when whole content is ready ).
So  as the error indicate the problem occurs in index.php
what I did I inserted

```
ob_start();
```

at the beginning of index.php

Answer (score 2):

This usually means that somewhere you've already got a `session_start()` and a second one will throw this error. Remove the redundant one.

Answer (score 2):

In this file may have blank space before start PHP tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try using @session_start(); It will bypass the error and session will be start. 
Please note @session_start() is your first line of the code. Do not execute or echo anything before it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the controller file, if there are spaces before the php tag remove it.

Answer (score 0):

check your files for extra spaces or enter, in my case, I have an extra enter in application/config/autoload.php before php tag (Iam using codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

```
 ob_start ([ callable $output_callback = NULL [, int $chunk_size = 0 [, int $flags = 
 PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_STDFLAGS ]]] ) : bool
```

> This function will turn output buffering on. While output buffering is
>   active no output is sent from the script (other than headers), instead
>   the output is stored in an internal buffer.
>
> The contents of this internal buffer may be copied into a string
>   variable using ob_get_contents(). To output what is stored in the
>   internal buffer, use ob_end_flush(). Alternatively, ob_end_clean()
>   will silently discard the buffer contents.

Answer (score 0):

I had to go to php.ini and remove comment from `always_populate_raw_post_data = -1` line.